# Inline VisualForce Page showing VF Page name in Salesforce1 mobile app and not in browser version

Tags: salesforce1-app, inline-visualforce

I have made a Visualforce Page with a PageBlockTable in it, but when I add this page to a layout as inline Visualforce and try to display it in the Salesforce1 Mobile App the Page Name is showing up above the PageBlock and PageBlockTable. So the name before the .page extension. In the browser version this is not showing up. Is this a bug? Anyone else has noticed a similar issue?

This is my code snippet :

```
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">            
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Something}" var="index">                         
            <apex:column onClick="sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!index.Something}');" value="{!index.Something}"/> 
            <apex:column onClick="sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!index.Something}')" value="{!index.Something}"/>  
            <apex:column onClick="sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!index.Something}')" value="{!index.Something}"/>   
            <apex:column value="{!index.Something}" onclick="
                                if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                                    console.log('mobile');
                                    sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!index.Something}');
                                }
                                else {
                                    console.log('web');
                                    readCell('Something');
                                };" >                 
            </apex:column>  
            <apex:column>
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!readCellMethod}">
                    <apex:param assignTo="{!Something}" value="{!index.Something}" name="Something" />
                </apex:commandButton>       
            </apex:column>        
        </apex:pageblocktable>   
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your code snippet?

Comment: I have added my code snippet

Comment: I have also noticed this as well. I am currently investigating resolutions to this. Please post if you have found anything in your research.